# MySQL select multiple columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation

I have two tables

card_index

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| uid | id1 | id2 | id3 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 125 | 129 | 145 |
|  2  | 127 | 128 | 132 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

and card_data

```
+----+------------+----------+...
| id |  last_use  |  active  |
+----+------------+----------+...
| 125| 10-07-2014 |   true   |
| 127| 27-02-2014 |   true   |
| 128| 15-06-2014 |   true   |
| 129| 10-01-2013 |   false  |
+----+------------+----------+... and so on
```

I want to select all data from 'card_data' by 'uid' from 'card_index', so the result for 'uid' = 1 should look like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id |  last_use  |  active  |
+----+------------+----------+
| 125| 10-07-2014 |   true   |
| 129| 10-01-2013 |   false  |
| 145| 13-01-2013 |   true   |
+----+------------+----------+
```

The SQL query I made is:

```
SELECT * FROM card_data WHERE id IN (SELECT CONCAT(id1,',',id2,',',id3) FROM card_index WHERE uid = 1);
```

However it only selects firts row:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id |  last_use  |  active  |
+----+------------+----------+
| 125| 10-07-2014 |   true   |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know what's wrong.
I'm using mysql-server 5.5.38-log, compiled from source on FreeBSD

Comment: I suggest normalising the data first.

Comment: isn't joining the tables easier ? 
```INNER JOIN ON id1=id OR id2=id OR id3=id```

Comment: @kjtl And by normalising the data you mean what. I'm not able to alter these tables. I'd have to rework everithing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `INNER JOIN` instead of combination of `CONCAT` and `WHERE id IN`  worked for me.
Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM card_data
INNER JOIN card_index ON id1=id OR id2=id OR id3=id
WHERE uid = 1;
```

And the desired result:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id |  last_use  |  active  |
+----+------------+----------+
| 125| 10-07-2014 |   true   |
| 129| 10-01-2013 |   false  |
| 145| 13-01-2013 |   true   |
+----+------------+----------+
```